# Is there a way for the bot to know what channel is user connected with?

Tags: botframework

Webchat/facebook/twillio etc
We'd want to have to programmatically recognize the channel used in the bot code

Comment: Are you using .Net or Javascript ?

Answer (score 4):

In **C#** you can check the user's Channel Id from the context here's an example:

```cs
Context.Activity.ChannelId
```

You can then switch on the channel id

```cs
   switch (innerDc.Context.Activity.ChannelId)
                {
                    case "directline":
                        break;
                    case "facebook":
                        break;
                    case "":
                        break;
                    case "":
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
```

in **NodeJS** you also get the channel id from the context, here's an example:

```js
turnContext.activity.channelId
```

Check the different ChannelIDs used [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.channelids?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0)

Comment: Is there a way not to use hardcoded strings? the link to the doc is version 3.0 and that ChannelIds class is not in 4.0

Comment: @zape i have created channelIDs enum and i use it across my project those channelIds in the 3.0 doc i think are still the same so i use those

Comment: Found it. It is in Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Channels now